# How to force a widget to appear on lock screen programmatically (Android)

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to force a widget to appear on the lock screen in Android.

Any ideas or code examples?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? As you're new to SO I recommend checking out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your Q for others to help.

Comment: I just designed the widget, and searched for how to force it to appear on the lock screen programatically and I found nothing :S

Answer (score 0):

First, the standard Android lockscreen framework only supports app widgets from Android 4.1 through 4.4, which is a steadily shrinking portion of the Android device ecosystem.

Second, there is no programmatic means, in standard Android, to force the user to add an app widget to the home screen or to the lockscreen.

Comment: Thank you for your support :)

Comment: Actually, I have a requirement of showing a widget on lock screen for showing emergency information. As per the documentation google is not supporting lock screen widget but still I can see this app `app.medicalid.free` still showing. Can you please put some light on how they are doing it?