# Display Application widget on Lock screen android

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen

I am stuck with one of my client requirement , it seems not be feasible to me as i am not able to find anything related to this particular requirement.I am goggling but does not came up with proper clue.I though studied the below mentioned link which states that it is not supportive . **Here is the link** :-

[How to force a widget to appear on lock screen programmatically (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840622/how-to-force-a-widget-to-appear-on-lock-screen-programmatically-android)

i just want to confirm that is it feasible ? Or this can be achieved by making custom lock screen for application.

**Here is what my client requirement is** :-
[image]

I need your suggestion here , please let me know .

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> i just want to confirm that is it feasible ?

As I wrote in the answer to the question that you linked to, the standard Android lockscreen framework only supports app widgets from Android 4.1 through 4.4, which is a steadily shrinking portion of the Android device ecosystem.

> Or this can be achieved by making custom lock screen for application.

Android does not support the creation of custom lockscreens, other than by building your own modified version of Android, poured into your own custom ROM, installed onto whatever hardware your custom ROM supports.

There are plenty of developers who *claim* to create custom lockscreens. Those actually require you to disable the device lockscreen, then their apps attempt to interpose themselves between the user and ordinary apps. At the best of times, this offers weaker security.

Comment: @CommonsWares , Thanks for your reply , so i need to create custom Lock screen for this and have to replace it with default ?

Comment: @sid: As I wrote in my answer, Android does not offer custom lockscreens. Before you try writing a fake custom lockscreen, please spend time with your attorney.

Comment: @CommonsWares , i totally respect your words sir , may be i am little confused , as we can see that we  are having many applications out there in playstore which customize our device theme and even display it's custom options on our Lock screen for example there are many launchers available. I am really confused here , or i am really miss-understood the concept of displaying widget on lock screen.

Comment: @sid: "there are many launchers available" -- a "launcher" (a.k.a., home screen) is not a lockscreen.